# Restore Backup in sql server

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have a Sql server DataBase.i have a complete Backup in one day of week and differential backup in every day.

if my DataBase damage,how i can Restore Complete And Last Differential Backup together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to restore these in sequence (and FYI I'd recommend adding a transaction log backup to the mix) - see this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477.aspx)

I would also recommend using Redgate's SQLBackup - it's fantastic, and in my experience much better than the built in SQL backup.

Answer (score 0):

When you do need to restore from your backups you will have to select the recovery state from the options menu in the restore window. You will want to select "Restore with norecovery" with the default option checked you won't be able to restore additional logs.

@Bob Palmer is correct if the DB is in production you should think about doing transaction log backups at least once an hour.